# React + TS + hooks problem at action dispatch

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-context

Please tell me what im doing wrong in here:

I get the following error
Type '{ wishList: any; addBookToWishList: (book: any) => void; }' is not assignable to type '{ wishList: never[]; }'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'addBookToWishList' does not exist in type '{ wishList: never[]; }'.ts(2322)

```
import React, {createContext, useReducer, useEffect} from "react";
import AppReducer from "./AppReducer";

//initial state
const initialState = {
    wishList: [],
}

//create context
export const GlobalContext = createContext(initialState);

//provider component

export const GlobalProvider = (props:any) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(AppReducer, initialState);

    

// actions
const addBookToWishList = (book : any) => {
    dispatch({ type: "ADD_BOOK_TO_WISHLIST", payload: book })

    return(
        <GlobalContext.Provider 
          value={{
            wishList: state.wishList,
            addBookToWishList,
          }}
        >
          {props.children}
        </GlobalContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

Comment: You’ve got a lot of missing and mismatched curly braces.    Your return statement is actually within the addBookToWishlist function because you’re missing the } on the end.

Answer (score 1):

What a mess...
first create type of your wish list item;

i gess book

```
  type Book = {
      title: string,
  }

 
  const initState = {
      wishList: new Array<Book>(),
  }

  const addBookToWishList = (book: Book) => {
    dispatch({ type: "ADD_BOOK_TO_WISHLIST", payload: book })
```